# Swift build fails to link during Travis CI test

Tags: swift, macos, travis-ci

I have a Swift project for which I'm using Travis CI. I develop mainly on Linux so I've only concerned myself with setting up Travis to run the tests on Linux (which all run just fine). I'm now trying to extend things to also run the tests on macOS. I've successfully built and run the tests on macOS manually. The problem I'm running into is that Travis fails with linker errors on macOS, even though I believe I am using the same process/commands that I used to manually run them. I presume I'm either configuring Travis wrong (most likely this since Travis is completely new to me), or I'm just misunderstanding how things work on a mac (also likely since I'm new to apple).

Here's my .travis.yml file:

```
matrix:
  include:
  - os: linux
    dist: trusty
    sudo: required  
  - os: osx
    osx_image: xcode8
  allow_failures:
  - os: osx
before_install:
- if [[ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" == "linux" ]]; then 
    sudo apt-get update;      
    sudo apt-get install liblapack3 liblapacke liblapacke-dev -y;  
    sudo apt-get install libopenblas-base libopenblas-dev -y;    
  fi
- if [[ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" == "osx" ]]; then 
    brew update;
    brew install homebrew/dupes/lapack;
    brew install homebrew/science/openblas;
    ls /usr/local/opt/openblas/lib;
  fi  
- git clone https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Package-Builder.git
script:
- ./Package-Builder/build-package.sh -projectDir $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR
```

As you can see, my project depends on LAPACK and OpenBLAS, which I install before building. From the Travis job log, the OpenBLAS install appears to succeed (as does LAPACK). I get the following notice from brew,

```
This formula is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local.
macOS already provides this software and installing another version in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

Generally there are no consequences of this for you. If you build your
own software and it requires this formula, you'll need to add to your
build variables:

    LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/openblas/lib
    CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/openblas/include
```

and the result of the `ls /usr/local/opt/openblas/lib` shows,

```
cmake               libopenblas.dylib
libblas.dylib       libopenblasp-r0.2.18.a
liblapack.dylib         libopenblasp-r0.2.18.dylib
libopenblas.a
```

So far, so good. As you can see, I'm using IBM's Package Builder project to actually build the Swift project. I have it configured to build on macOS with the following command:

```
swift build -Xlinker -L/usr/local/opt/lapack/lib -Xlinker -L/usr/local/opt/openblas/lib
```

The job log shows that this is indeed the command being run to build the project.

Compilation succeeds, but in linking I get the following error:

```
Linking ./.build/debug/NiftyPackageTests.xctest/Contents/MacOS/NiftyPackageTests
ld: library not found for -lopenblas for architecture x86_64
<unknown>:0: error: link command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
<unknown>:0: error: build had 1 command failures
```

This is surprising to me since I can see that the library is located in a directory that I can also see has been added to my library link search path.

I tried adding `-Xlinker -v` to the build command, hoping for some useful info, but that doesn't give any extra output.

Any ideas what's going wrong or where to go from here? Maybe there's a better approach? I don't have an xcode project and I didn't think I'd need one, but I can make one if that would be better. Is there something wrong with installing OpenBLAS the way I did, which brew says is a duplicate? I couldn't find it preinstalled or figure out how to link against it so I had to brew install to get it to work when I did this manually.

EDIT: you can see the Travis log [here](https://travis-ci.org/nifty-swift/Nifty/jobs/194148479)

Comment: did you try this? `-Xcc -I/usr/local/opt/openblas/include` ( see [this question "xcode-ld-library-not-found-for-architecture-x86-64"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35321202/xcode-ld-library-not-found-for-architecture-x86-64))

Comment: I just tried that thanks, unfortunately it didn't change anything

Comment: Though, the question you linked led me to try adding the link directives to lapacke and openblas to the build command... not sure why this makes a difference as that is specified in the module map... anyway, it now no longer complains about being unable to find the library, but complains about undefined symbols... https://travis-ci.org/nifty-swift/Nifty/jobs/194152930

Comment: best you create a new question with new infos or add the new info to the question