# library not found for -lswiftCoreFoundation for architecture x86_64

Tags: swift, xcode, static-libraries

I have workspace contains subprojects and one of the subproject generates static lib which is linked to main project. I have created a swift in static lib subproject and I get below build error.

```
library not found for -lswiftCoreFoundation for architecture x86_64
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35321202/xcode-ld-library-not-found-for-architecture-x86-64

Comment: I check the above link, those are including external libs. But my case seems to be like system lib not found.

Comment: Nevertheless, you've given insufficient information to reproduce the problem (you've described your setup in only the most vague terms). So your question, as it stands, adds nothing new to the mix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution: Add one .swift file to application target and it works